# SQL SERVER UNIQUE only when other column value difference

Tags: sql-server

i need help for table design with specific unique term.
The table will look like this.

```
id --> Primary key auto generate
type1 --> varchar(20)
type2 --> varchar(20)
code --> int
```

The code column is unique but allow same value only when column type2 have same value.

```
1  xyz  freedom  6773
2  asd  freedom  6773
3  rty  prison   6773 --> not allowed
4  pop  prison   7809
```

Comment: I think this can be done on server side code than expecting to do in database. Though I am not sure if such capabilities are given by sql-server but I would have implemented such cases by programming on server side when inserting any data to this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As variat you can use additional table with all the posible combinations of (code,type2).

```
CREATE TABLE checkTable(
  code int NOT NULL,
  type2 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_checkTable_code PRIMARY KEY(code),
CONSTRAINT UK_checkTable_type2 UNIQUE(type2),
CONSTRAINT UK_checkTable_code_type2 UNIQUE(code,type2) -- it's using for FK in your table
)

CREATE TABLE yourTable(
  id int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  type1 varchar(20),
  type2 varchar(20),
  code int,
CONSTRAINT PK_yourTable PRIMARY KEY(id),
CONSTRAINT FK_yourTable_code_type2 FOREIGN KEY(code,type2) REFERENCES checkTable(code,type2)
)
```

I hope that I understood rightly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think trigger might be usefull in your case ...below is a pseudo code

```
create trigger trg_test
on table1
after insert
as
begin

if exists(
Select  * from inserted  i
          join
          tab1e1 t1
          on t1.code=i.code and i.type2<>t1.type2
          )
Rollback;
end
```

**Some testing::**

below code fails

```
insert into table1
values
('prison',6773)
```

below code succeeds

```
insert into table1
values
('prison',6774)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you like to insert same value, cannot define code as UNIQUE column.

For your case, I would suggest to remove id (auto increase primary key) and make type02 + code as Composite primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a column unique if you want to allow same value even if there is a condition (it is not even possible to put condition to the index)

You need to handle the validation in your application.